# How to create with Cmake: POST BUILD EVENT for Visual Studio, Debugging Command and Debugging command arguments

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I'm trying to create the following "Post-Build Event" for Visual Studio in a CMakeLists.txt.

```
copy $(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt) $(SDK_PATH)\bin\exmp.dll
```

I found this to use with my library (vibe_mdl):

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET vibe_mdl 
    POST_BUILD ...
)
```

but I can't find a way to have the string that I need to be populated to the Post Build event.

I also need to set the "Debugging Command" in "Configuration Properties" with `$(SDK_PATH)\bin\bl_sim5.exe` and the "Debugging Command Arguments" with -o (this one should be easy)

Any help is strongly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're trying to do here, but there are existing questions about copying files in post-build events on this site. However rather than copying the files to a location, usually it's simplest to just specify one directory for writing the dlls to without the need to output them and simply use `VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT` to add them to the path when debugging via VS: `set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/binaries/$<CONFIG>") ... set_target_properties(myexe PROPERTIES VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT "PATH=${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY};$ENV{PATH}")`

Comment: When I copy the file I need to change its name from the build name to the name that I have. The other issue that I can't solve is how to use the environment variable $(SDK_PATH) which is the place where I want to copy it.

This also applies to the Debugging command. 
Currently, I set it in the generated VS settings but if Cmake detects a change every time I have to do it again, which is plain stupid.

So, is cmake is flexible enough or not do what I'd like to do or not.

Comment: I'm building a DLL, and so in the debugging command I need to write the path of the exe, this path is using the $(SDK_PATH) environment variable. How do I get the string in the debugging command to contain that env variable?
More simply, how do I get Cmake to create the string $(SDK_PATH)\bin\bl_sim5.exe in the debugging command.

Currently, I set what I need manually in the generated VS settings but if Cmake detects a change, I have to do it again, which is plain stupid.

So, is cmake flexible enough to do that or not?